# Remove every 10 digit number

Tags: python, regex

I have a huge collection of files that I am trying to rename in bulk. The patterns of these filenames are somewhat consistent but there are few bumps that render my basic regex knowledge inadequate.

The filenames usually go like this:
`1050327473 {913EDD51} 1st Filename [2nd Edition].txt`

I could remove the strings between `{}`, `[]`, and few other special characters with this piece of code:

```
new_file_name = re.sub(r'{.+?}', '', filename)
new_file_name = re.sub(r'\[.+?]', '', new_file_name)
new_file_name = ((new_file_name.split(" .pdf", 1)[0]) + '.pdf').translate({ord(i):None for i in '/\:*?"<>|_'})
```

and it successfully outputs this:

`1050327473 1st Filename`

However some of the original filenames are different than the pattern and I still have to remove the 10 digit number. Few of the other patterns are like this:

```
785723041X, 4844004976 {2C5ACB07} 1st Filename.txt
0383948600 {6A7528B5} 2nd Filename.txt
3263031418, 7966530910, 8070331430 {DCBAD13B} 3rd Filename.txt
```

The expect output is

```
1st Filename.txt
2nd Filename.txt
3rd Filename.txt
```

Now, I could remove every bit of number characters but the file name would also lose a meaningful part of it and become `st Filename.txt`. Taking a certain part of the string array with something like `[10:]` would also not work because the length of this digit is interchangeable.

I thought the most logical thing would be to remove every 10 digit character but some of the 10 digit number sequences end with an X instead of the 10th digit, like `785723041X`. Also, if the 10 digit sequence is followed by a comma that should be removed too.

What would be the best approach to solve this problem? Is it doable with regex only?

Comment: post the expected result for those 3 file patterns

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. Edited the question

Comment: The 10 digit part looks like `r'\d{9}[0-9X],?'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With specific regex pattern:

```
import re

filenames = ['785723041X, 4844004976 {2C5ACB07} 1st Filename.txt',
             '0383948600 {6A7528B5} 2nd Filename.txt',
             '3263031418, 7966530910, 8070331430 {DCBAD13B} 3rd Filename.txt']

pat = re.compile(r'\{[^{}]+\}|\[[^[]]+\]|\b\d{9}[\dX],?')
filenames = [pat.sub('', f).strip() for f in filenames]
print(filenames)
```

The output:

```
['1st Filename.txt', '2nd Filename.txt', '3rd Filename.txt']
```

---

Regex details:

- `..|..|..` - alternation group (to match a single regular expression out of several possible regular expressions)
- `\{[^{}]+\}` - match any characters enclosed with `{}` (except themselves, ensured by character class `[^{}]+`)
- `\[[^[]]+\]` - match any characters enclosed with `[]` (except themselves, ensured by character class `[^[]]+`)
- `\b\d{9}[\dX],?` - match 9-digit sequence followed either by 10th digit or `X` char and optional trailing `,` char